# How one stored procedure can read first recordset from another's execution results?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to call stored procedure `Foo` from another stored procedure  `Bar`. The thing is that `Foo` returns **2 recordsets** and in `Bar` I want to analyze only the first one.

I've found many advice on how to deal with a single recordset as a callee stored procedure result. But nothing about multiple.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [How to share data between stored procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)

Comment: Just to be more clear, here 2 recordsets means two selects?

Comment: @Anil yes, two `SELECT`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done in pure transact SQL, only if you create a CLR-stored procedure (AKA, sp written in .NET)

If you have access to `Foo` - you can add a parameter to it, to tell which result-set to return.

Something like this pseudo-code:

```
ALTER Procedure dbo.Foo
(
  @ResultSetIndicator smallint = 0
)
AS

BEGIN

    if (@ResultSetIndicator = 0)
    BEGIN 
        SELECT xxx
    END

    if (@ResultSetIndicator = 1)
    BEGIN 
        SELECT yyy
    END
END
```

Comment: Probably it's really impossible in pure TSQL because it doesn't contain an entity to store such structure. Thank you for the answer and CLR-stored procedure option.

Comment: @Zharro yes, and even if you try to `INSERT INTO xxx EXEC Foo` the server will complain that your two result-sets have different column number , different column names etc.